# Unload after from package import *

Tags: python

Is there a way to clear the namespace after an import like:

```
from pandas import *
```

Ps: I know it's the worse way possible. It's for educational purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clear globals entirely (built-ins remain, but nothing else you've defined or imported) with:

```
globals().clear()
```

`globals()` returns the `dict` representing the global namespace, and like all `dict`s, it has a `clear` method to remove all mappings from it.

If you want to limit it to what came from `pandas` only, assuming it defines `__all__` (I don't know if `pandas` specifically does), you could do something like:

```
import pandas
for name in pandas.__all__:
    del globals()[name]
```

since `from SOMEMODULE import *`, for a package/module defining `__all__`, definitionally imports the names listed in `__all__`, so this unmaps those names specifically. If it doesn't, you're stuck with a slightly uglier heuristic for the case when `__all__` is not defined, which I believe is just "does it start with an underscore?", so you could do:

```
import pandas
for name in vars(pandas):
    if not name.startswith('_'):
        del globals()[name]
```